# How to display table of textviews in android eclipse?

Tags: android, arrays, list

I currently have a two-dimensional array of strings that contains information from
a website on the internet. How can I use this array to display a table of `TextViews` where
each textview would contain a text from the array?

Any help would be greatly appreciated thnx.

Answer (score 1):

You would probably want to use a **`ListView`**.

A `ListView` can be used to display the data that you have in the array with each row in the list displaying a text from the array.

Have a look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) here.

**EDIT :** 
There is another way of doing it, which is closer to your actual idea of a table of TextViews.

You can define a vertical LinearLayout and then run a loop through your array, and for every element in the array dynamically add a TextView to the LinearLayout.

This method is more complex than using the ListView and I would *suggest you to go for the ListView* if you are not very much acquainted with Android.